# How can I automatically answer a call to an Android device with a busy signal?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm developing a toy Android app: one of its functions is that it looks at incoming calls and if the calling number is in a blacklist, automatically closes the call. I'm having a problem making that work. I'm referencing `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` to close the incoming call.

Is there a way to let the caller think that I'm in another call (busy)? Or to let the caller think that my phone is off or has no reception?

Answer (score 1):

**use airplane mode**

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(mcontext.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED); 
intent.putExtra("state", 1); 
mcontext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE")); 
mcontext.sendBroadcast(intent); 
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(mcontext.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
intent.putExtra("state", 0); 
mcontext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE")); 
mcontext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, I gonna try... but I suspect that calling user hears at least one free signal before going to airplane mode. Anyway, something to try I did not think about. Thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome.try the above code. and also try it binding with a serviced method or else once the app closes it would stop acting. so u need a service to work in background